# SQL query to pull the values for a record from table?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So im basically trying to use a customer ID to pull customer information like name, address, phone etc. from a table to be used to pre-fill certain textboxes in the form. I have it linked to a button press that searches another table called CustomerID to see if the phone number exists in the "phone" column and if so returns the cusID associated with it, i do this using Dlookup which seems to work. Then I want to use the cusID to find the corresponding customer information from the table CustomerInfo using the SQL query below but it just throws up a "Run-time elso rror '13' Type mismatch" on the SQL query line. I've tried a bunch of different formatting for it and cannot seem to get it to work, any one know what i'm doing wrong? Also is it even possible to parse the SQL query data into individual textboxes? Also code is below

```
Private Sub querycust_Click()
phonesearch = DLookup("cusID", "CustomerID", "phone='" & 9999999999# & "'")
If IsNull(phonesearch) Then
    MsgBox ("No Customer ID Exists For This Phone Number")
    
ElseIf Not IsNull(phonesearch) Then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT " * " FROM CustomerInfo WHERE [CustomerInfo]![CusID]=phonesearch"
    


End If


End Sub
```

Comment: `"SELECT  *  FROM CustomerInfo WHERE [CustomerInfo]![CusID]=" & phonesearch`

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL` is used for action queries, not returning data.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the reply! I just tried that and its throwing another error now "Run-time error 2342, A runsql action requires an argument consisting of an SQL statement"

Comment: @Applecore Yeah i was reading around on the other threads and saw someone mention that but not any alternatives, how would you go about getting the corresponding data then in VBA?

Comment: You could try setting the `.Recordsource` of your form to the SQL statement that you have created. Or possibly, open a Recordset using the SQL statement, and then set the controls as needed. Unless you need all of the fields from the table, just select those that will be used, as it will be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub querycust_Click()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Sql As String

    Sql = "Select * From CustomerInfo Where phone = '9999999999'"
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)
    If Records.RecordCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Customer ID Exists For This Phone Number"
    Else
        Me!txtCustomerID = Records!cusID.Value
        ' More controls and values.
    End If
    Records.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried it, it throws "Too few parameters, expected 1" at the Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql) line

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Private Sub querycust_Click()
   cusID = DLookup("cusID", "CustomerID", "phone='" & 9999999999# & "'")
   If IsNull(cusID) Then
      MsgBox ("No Customer ID Exists For This Phone Number")    
   Else
      me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo WHERE CustomerID = " & CusID    
   end if
end Sub
```

so above will load up the form and all the textboxes etc with the data from that one sql statement.

Comment: Okay and how would i go about binding the textboxes to the query data? The textboxes are currently unbound

Comment: They should be bound. You can just set the forms data source in the forms property sheet to the table. Now each control will let you select a column name from the table. Then remove the data source of the form, since our above sample code is going to set the data source for us in code. You could also say use the wizard to create a new form (this would depend on how much work + effort you have in the existing form). So, set the form to the table - you can then bind the controls. then remove the table (setting) as the data source when done.